# suprema and infima of sets without proof - Abbott 1.3.8

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

This problem comes from *Understanding Analysis* by Abbott.

> **1.3.8** Compute, without proofs, the suprema and infima (if they exist) of the following sets:
>
> (a) $ \{ m/n : m,n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ with } m<n \} $
>
> (b) $ \{ (-1)^m / n : m,n \in \mathbb{N} \} $
>
> (c) $ \{ n/(3n+1) : n \in \mathbb{N} \} $
>
> (d) $ \{ m/(m+n) : m,n \in \mathbb{N} \} $

Assume $A$ represents the set in context. My answers:

(a) I believe this should be $\sup A = 1$, because $m \ngeq n$ then $m/n$ can't be $1$ or greater, but it continuously gets closer. I wasn't sure here either $\inf A = 0$ or $\inf A = 1/2$ I think depending on the inclusion of $0$.

(b) This has $\min \{A\} = -1$ and $\max \{A\} = 1$, so $\inf A = -1$ and $\sup A = 1$.

(c) The values seem to be approaching $1/3$, so I answered $\sup A= 1/3$, and again I'm not sure if $\inf A = 0$ or $\inf A = 1/4$.

(d) $\inf A = 0$ (think huge $n$ and small $m$)  and $\sup A = 1/2$ or $\sup A = 1$ depending on whether $n$ can be $0$ or not.

Any corrections?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, 0 is a natural number. How you feel about it is up to you though, but generally everything is more readable if you pick one and stick with it (for a certain solution). But at **(d)**, if we assume $n>0$, then $\sup A =1$ for what if we set $n=1$ and $m\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: For Abbott, 0 is not in the set $\mathbb{N}$. It's defined on page 2.

Comment: (a) $\sup A = 1$ and  $\inf A = 0$

Comment: (b) $\sup A = 1$ and $\inf A = -1$

Comment: (c) $\sup A = \dfrac{1}{3}$ and $\inf A = \dfrac{1}{4}$

Comment: (d) $\sup A = 1$ and $\inf A = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning for (a) is incorrect: if you fix $m=1$ and let $n \rightarrow \infty,$ we get $1/n \rightarrow 0.$ So $\inf A = 0.$

The others seem fine. Usually in analysis $\mathbb N$ does not include $0$ and judging by (b) I would assume this convention is taken here. It is likely that the author lists his notational conventions near the start of the book, so you should check there.

Comment: thanks for the answer and tip! I checked and the book does not include $0$.